# Count occurrences of items in a MySQL JSON field

Tags: mysql

I have a set of rows each containing a JSON field type, which contains an array of integers:

```
Row 1: [1, 2, 4]
Row 2: [null, 2, 4]
Row 3: [1, null, 4]
```

Is there a way (preferably a MySQL function, as I'm trying to avoid doing this logic in my php script) to find out the count for each item, such that the result from the query would be:

```
[2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Count unique value?

Comment: Count the occurrences for each item. For example the value '1' appears twice in those 3 rows. The number '2' appears twice also, and number '4' appears three times. So the result would be [2, 2, 3]. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible in SQL. If you want to support this kind of queries you will have to store the individual values as rows in a separate lookup table (with a reference to the corresponding parent row) and then use GROUP_CONCAT() to get them as list of values

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I thought that might be the case unfortunately. Would be amazing if MySQL had a count function for JSON field types containing arrays like this.

Comment: Maybe the reference can help you. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html